# NGINX configuration to allow built React assets to communicate with deployed backend

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have NGINX running on a VM, along with a Spring Boot backend. The backend is working fine, and I am able to hit it's endpoints. I am serving a built React application with NGINX, but it is not able to communicate with the backend.

When I try to do something on the UI and hit a backend endpoint, I get the following error -
`Refused to connect to <backend-url> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback`.

My backend is served over HTTP, whereas my frontend is served over HTTPS, both on the same VM.
I can try serving the frontend over HTTP too and see if it works.

Other than that, what changes could I make in my nginx.conf to make this work?

Comment: Seems the issue is related to the CSP(Content Security Policy). Please try sending both applications over the same protocol and try. You can also set up a reverse proxy with the Nginx for some requests.
Something like :
location /test 
{ proxy_pass http://localhost:8090 }